# sed remembered pattern output not returning anything I expected

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following string:

```
"date" : dateFunc("2019-12-01T00:00:00Z")
```

When I try to grab any back reference using sed, I am not getting what I think I should get.

For example, this is what shows if I **egrep -o** with the same regex:

```
$ echo '"date" : dateFunc("2019-12-01T00:00:00Z")' | egrep -o '(" : )'
" : 
$ echo '"date" : dateFunc("2019-12-01T00:00:00Z")' | egrep -o '(" : )(dateFunc)'
" : dateFunc
$ echo '"date" : dateFunc("2019-12-01T00:00:00Z")' | egrep -o '(" : )(dateFunc)([(])'
" : dateFunc(
```

Now, if I apply the same regexes in sed, I expected the following:

for `\1` to produce `" :`

for `\2` to produce `dateFunc`

for `\3` to produce `(`

However, what I got was the following:

```
$ echo '"date" : dateFunc("2019-12-01T00:00:00Z")' | sed -r 's/(" : )(dateFunc)([(])/\1/g'
"date" : "2019-12-01T00:00:00Z")
$ echo '"date" : dateFunc("2019-12-01T00:00:00Z")' | sed -r 's/(" : )(dateFunc)([(])/\2/g'
"datedateFunc"2019-12-01T00:00:00Z")
$ echo '"date" : dateFunc("2019-12-01T00:00:00Z")' | sed -r 's/(" : )(dateFunc)([(])/\3/g'
"date("2019-12-01T00:00:00Z")
```

Comment: Could you please post expected output in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what matches:

```
    "date" : dateFunc("2019-12-01T00:00:00Z")
1:       ~~~~
2:           ~~~~~~~~  
3:                   ~
```

And this is how the substitution works (I replaced spaces by `_`, the remaining spaces are there just to show the alignment):

```
    "date" : dateFunc("2019-12-01T00:00:00Z")
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 1: "date"_:_         "2019-12-01T00:00:00Z")
 2: "date    dateFunc "2019-12-01T00:00:00Z")
 3: "date            ("2019-12-01T00:00:00Z")
```

So, sed is returning exactly what you asked it to return.

sed replaces *only the matching parts*, while `grep -o` *shows* them. Maybe you wanted

```
sed -r 's/.*(" : )(dateFunc)([(]).*/\1/g'
          ~~                     ~~
          ^                       ^
          |                       |
       Match anything           Match anything
       before                   after
```

Comment: In other words, `sed s///` doesn't automatically throw away everything that wasn't matched, whereas `grep -o` does.